# Python - Looping over a string

Tags: python, grok

How would loop the word that a user can input like the example below in python.

**Enter a word: python** (User can input any word)

p

py

pyt

pyth

pytho

python

(Then it loops the word inputted by the user)

Comment: What have you tried and where did you fail ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two more approaches!

Functional:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

in_word = input("Enter a word: ")

print("\n".join(\
    map(lambda x:in_word[:x], range(1,len(in_word)+1)) \
    ))
```

Using recursion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

in_word = input("Enter a word: ")

def print_word_recurse(word):
    if(not word): return
    print_word_recurse(word[:-1])
    print(word)


print_word_recurse(in_word)
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be better ways to do this, but this is the simplest:

```
string = 'python'

for index in range(1, len(string)):
    print(string[:index])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, using Python 3 <sup>(1)</sup>:

```
>>> s = input('Enter string: ')
Enter string: python

>>> for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
...     print(s[:i])
...
p
py
pyt
pyth
pytho
python
```

It uses `input()` to prompt for, and get, a string from the user.

It then iterates the `i` variable from `1` to the length of the string (inclusive), each time printing out that many characters at the beginning of the string.

---

Once you become more adept at Python's potential for terseness, you could replace the `for` loop with something like:

```
print(*[s[:i] for i in range(1,len(s)+1)],sep='\n')
```

or:

```
print("\n".join([s[:i] for i in range(1,len(s)+1)]))
```

but you may find that the readable solution is still the *best* :-)

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If you're stuck on Python 2 for some reason, remember to use `raw_input()` and remove the parentheses from the `print` line.